# Updating multiple records in mySQL table via PHP web form table?

Tags: php, mysql, insert-update

Need a little help...

I have a basic html table with text field form in last column and a hidden field on each row of the web table.  The data in this table is extracted out of a table in the database.

I want my users to be able to update one field in the database (a score)  using this web form (page).

I have a hidden web form component on each row that contains the unique id of the record in the database for each row in the web page table.

I was attempting to create code that would   update the entire list of entries on the web form, even if the user is not updating that particular field. (The values of the scores field are populated into the web form at the creation of the table. So if you did not update any scores, but hit the submit button, it would update the database table with the same values.)

Here’s my code: (abbreviated to save bytes…)

```
<?php

//Do all the database connection stuff up front


if (isset($_POST[‘score’]))
{
     $student_id = $_POST[‘student_id’];
      $score = $_POST['score'];
      $n        = count($score);
       $i        = 0;

echo "You have updated these student scores on this assignment. \r\n" .
"<ol>";
   while ($i < $n)
{
echo "<hr><P>{$score[$i]} \r\n";
echo "<hr><P>{$student_id[$i]} \r\n";

$qry = "UPDATE assignments SET score = ".$score[$i]." WHERE student_id = " .$student_id[$i]. '"';
$result=@mysql_query($qry);

$i++;
   }
}
if($result) {
        header("location: member-index.php");
        exit();
    }else {
        die("Query failed");
    }
?>
```

Am I on the right track? Is there a better way to do what I’m attempting? All suggestions and ideas welcome!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: FYI `header()` will probably fail since you are echoing before the redirect.

Answer (score 0):

i'm guessing you are using

```
<input name="scores[]"/>
```

why not echo the unique id into the input name?

```
<input name="score[<?php echo $unique_id ?>]" />
```

this means in the loop, the $i would be the unique id (one less variable and less HTML).

and please use mysql_real_escape_string() when working with DB transactions. I know it's an example code but please don't forget that

Besides that, yes, you are on the right track

Comment: o, and use foreach :P not a while. More appropriate in this context

Comment: I think I understand what you're saying above. My web form fields are named "scores[]" and "student_id[]" ...which is the actual unique record info. However, I'm still getting a "Query failed" message on submitting. I'm very new to this so I think I need it more spelled out.